# Dynamically set the value of "Copy value from item" in Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

Say I created a BLOCK2 as a copy of BLOCK1. BLOCK3 is a detail block of BLOCK1 and I want to reuse it as well for BLOCK2. BLOCK3.FOREIGN_KEY is using the "Copy Value from Item" property to reference its value to BLOCK1.PRIMARY_KEY. **How can I set the "Copy Value from Item" property dynamically to reference the calling block's primary key?**

[image]

I've tried clearing the BLOCK3.FOREIGN_KEY's "Copy Value from Item" and set its value from the buttons that call BLOCK3 but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display `BLOCK3` (detail) data depending on whether its master is `BLOCK1` or `BLOCK2`.

If that's so, remove property you've been using so far. You'll have to - somehow - let Forms know which block is a source; one option is to use **buttons** in each of `BLOCK1` and `BLOCK2` which will set a **parameter** to desired value. Their `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` (WBP) triggers would be

```
:parameter.caller := 'block1';  -- block2 for BLOCK2's WBP trigger    
go_block('block3');
execute_query;
```

Then create `PRE-QUERY` `BLOCK3` block-level trigger and set it to

```
:block3.foreign_key_item := decode(:parameter.caller, 'block1', :block1.id,
                                                      'block2', :block2.id);
```

Comment: It worked! I had to place that :parameter.caller to a control block and use a CASE instead of decode in the pre-query. Thank you very much!